# Completeness property in signal analysis

Tags: hilbert-spaces, philosophy

Why completeness is an important property for signal analysis such as Fourier? What if we don't have a such a property?Many books discuss that the vector should not have a hole to complete.what is simplest test to check if a vector space is complete? Can someone explain this notion in a ***simple comprehensive*** way for me working in the area of signal processing. Thanks

Comment: signal analysis takes place in Hilbert space H because you need inner product ( space $l^2$ ), and Hilbert spaces are complete. space H is complete is every Cauchy sequence converges to some point a, and that a is in H. Can you tell more precisely where completnes was mentioned ?  Completnes is property that you use to prove theorems.

Comment: @jack:Thank you.Actually I know this formal explanation. I am looking for the causes. Now lets dig more according to your answer: Why signal analysis needs to happen in H? why we need inner product space?What is so special about Cauchy sequence in this context?

Comment: @ Normal Human,@Antonio Vargas,@darij grinberg, @Magdiragdag,@ Eric Wofsey: I hope this looks better. Looking forward hearing your views.

Comment: I really dont know anything about vector with or without hole , Vector space can be complete, I dont know about complete vectors. your space is complete because its Hilbert space , simplest way to check if space V is complete is to take any Cauchy sequence and show it converges in V (I dont know if there is other way at all). In sig.proc. you want to check if your signal f has some property, usualy by trying to represent f as a series $f(t)=\sum_n a_n g_n$ where $g_n$ are some functions, if $g_n$ are orthogonal basis of Hilbert space H you can get $a_n$ as $a_n = \langle f,g_n \rangle$